# Can I raise an event without using a button?

Tags: c#, asp.net

i am trying to raise an event from a User Control (ascx) to cause it's parent page (aspx) to refresh.

On the User Control (ascx):

```
    public event CommandEventHandler OrderLineUpdated;

    protected void btnDeleteRow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int intOrderLineId = 0;
        Int32.TryParse(lblOrderLineId.Text, out intOrderLineId);
        OrderLinesDataHelpers.DeleteOrderLine(intOrderLineId);
        OrderLineUpdated(this,  new CommandEventArgs("","" ));
    }
```

On my parent page:

```
    <uc1:OrderLineControl ID="OrderLineControl1" runat="server" onOrderLineUpdated="ControlUpdated"/>
```

In the code behind:

```
     protected void ControlUpdated(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
    {
        TotalButtonProcess();
    }
```

When I try to raise the event - OrderLineUpdated(this,  new CommandEventArgs("","" )) - I get a NullReferenceException.
How do I initialize the Event without attaching it to a button?

Comment: Please verify *where* you get that NRE.